# IntelliJ Spark Job Class not found exception

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-spark

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue.

I am trying execute a Spark Job through spark shell.

First i created a Jar file for my main program by following below steps:

> 1.File > Project Structure.
>
> 2.Select Tab "Artifacts".
>
> 3.Click green plus button near top of window.
>
> 4.Select JAR from Add drop down menu. Select "From modules with dependencies"
>
> 5.Select main class.
>
> 6.The radio button should be selecting "extract to the target JAR." Press OK.
>
> 7.Check the box "Build on make"
>
> 8.Press apply and OK.
>
> 9.From the main menu, select the build dropdown.
>
> 10.Select the option build artifacts.

Jar file name:  `jar_name`.

Class file name:  `ClassDriver`.

Command used to submit the Job in Spark shell :

```
spark-submit --class com.xxx.ClassDriver jar_name
```

Error am getting:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xxx.ClassDriver
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: you have to revise Spark-submit options... see http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html